# Distinguish a command not a native second transmitter

Tags: grep, find, ls, xargs

suppose

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# find . -maxdepth 2 -type d  | ls
bin   dev  home  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
```

ls did nothing, as a rescue I should reconstruct them to a list to ls

```
find . -type d | xargs ls
#millions of outputs
```

However, grep does a good job

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# find . -maxdepth 2 -type d  | grep home
./home
```

How could I distinguish a command was not born as a second transmitter from underly understanding rather than trying, error test and remember.

Comment: Read the fine manual of the program.

Comment: yes, and a big picture should be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you learn and remember what the various programs do, or you check the man pages.

The description of `ls` is:

> List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default)

where FILEs refers to the synopsis:

> ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...

The important part to remember about `ls` is that it will generate information about the "FILEs" you give it -- *on the command-line*. The manual does not describe any ways in which `ls` reads any input (from e.g., a pipe).

Contrast the `ls` man page with, say the `cat` man page, which says:

> cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> Concatenate FILE(s) to standard output. With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

With `cat`, you can `cat /some/file` or you can `echo hi | cat`.

Therefore, in your first example,

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d  | ls
```

`find` went and did some work and passed some (or no) directory names on its stdout, which became `ls`'s stdin, which `ls` promptly ignored. Since you gave `ls` no FILEs to list, it defaulted to listing the current directory.

In your second example,

```
find . -type d | xargs ls
```

`find` went and did (more) work, producing every directory it found on its stdout, which was in turn presented to `xargs` as stdin. The man page for `xargs` reads, in part:

> xargs reads items from the standard input ... and executes the command one or more times ...

so then `ls` is called as many times as is needed, given the number of lines of input on stdin.

The same idea translates to your third command:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d  | grep home
```

`find` passes any directory names to `grep`'s stdin; grep's man page says, again in part:

> grep searches the named input FILEs for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.  If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given, grep searches standard input.

The idea of a pipeline is a simple one, but a powerful one, and you simply have to know what kind of output a program produces and whether a program can consume input on its stdin.

`grep` is one of the most common tools to use in these situations. You can use it as the primary command:

```
grep some-text file1 file2 file3 ...
```

in which case `grep` knows the names of the files, or you can send it input on its stdin:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... | grep some-text
```

... in which case grep no now longer knows any filenames (`cat` knew them, then produced their contents to stdout), and so now grep cannot know which files contained the text -- only which lines matched.

It gets tempting to chain a bunch of commands together -- often termed a "one-liner" often semi-facetiously, as a "one-liner" can become long enough to wrap two a second line in a terminal window -- into a "pipeline". Here again, you have to know exactly how the programs are producing and consuming input.

Given files named `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`, you *can* do something like:

```
find . -name 'file*' | xargs cat
```

and you won't be surprised when `find` produces the three filenames as stdout --

```
file1 
file2 
file3
```

... to which xargs compiles a list and sends along to `cat` --

```
cat file1 file2 file3
```

... who sees those three filenames and dutifully dumps their contents to your screen.

Beware, then of a file named "file name here"; the above `find` command will output:

```
file name here
file1
file2
file3
```

... to which xags compiles a list for `cat` --

```
cat file name here file1 file2 file3
```

... to which `cat` complains (to stderr!):

> cat: file: No such file or directory
>
> cat: name: No such file or directory
>
> cat: here: No such file or directory

... followed by the contents of file1, file2, and file3.

You're now prepared to avoid this situation by using `find ... -exec` or alternatives such as `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to use NULLs as the delimiters for filenames.